Is it possible to add a comment with a timestamp in a postgres sql file?
I have a sql file in which a backup of a postgres table is being created.
I want to add a comment with a timestamp specifying the date the table was created (i.e. the sql was being executed). I am looking for something like:
COMMENT ON TABLE my_schema.my_table IS 'Table was created on <timestamp>';

When using psql this can be done using:
SELECT current_timestamp as timestamp
\gset
COMMENT ON TABLE my_schema.my_table IS 'Table was created on ':'timestamp';

Unfortunately this can not be done in a sql file.
How can I add a comment with dynamic content like a timestamp?
I tried to execute a sql file containing:
SELECT current_timestamp as timestamp
\gset
COMMENT ON TABLE my_schema.my_table IS 'Table was created on ':'timestamp';

